# Every graph G contains a path with d(G) edges (proof critique).

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

Curious to see whether my proof below is acceptable or not. Any feedback will be well received.

Many thanks.

Every graph G contains a path with $\delta(G)$ edges.

$\mathbf{Proof.}$ Let $G$ be a graph with $\delta(G)=d$, and vertex set $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},...,v_{n}\}$. Now consider the neighbourhood of a vertex $v_{i}$ with degree $d$. Each distinct vertex incident to $v_{i}$ will have a degree greater than or equal to $d$. This implies that graph $G$ has at least $d+1$ vertices, one with degree $d$ and the remaining vertices with degree at least $d$. $\delta(G)$ forces graph $G$ to be connected. Because there are at least $d+1$ vertices, there will exist a path with $d+1-1=d$ edges.

Comment: What's $\delta(G)$?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's the minimum degree of G.

Comment: First, the graph needs not be connected. Think of two copies of a complete graph. Also, just because a connected graph has $d+1$ vertices does not mean there is a path of length $d$. You'll need to really use the condition that $\delta(G) =d$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey @ D Poole, could I trouble you for your opinion on how to get this proof going? I thought about it some more, see [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955244/correct-process-for-proof-in-graph-theory), but am no closer to a neat proof.