# Correct process for proof in graph theory.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm working on what I'm sure is a fairly basic proof in graph theory. I must prove that

Every graph $G$ contains a path with $\delta G$ edges.

$\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree of the graph $G$.

I did ask a very premature question a few days ago about this proof, which was simply a result of my excitement. I'd like to revisit the problem now that I've had some time to think.

So far, my thoughts on how to show this are as follows (this is not a formal proof, just my thoughts on the order in which things need to be shown):

- Let $G$ be a graph with $\delta(G)=d$ and with an arbitrary number of components, possibly one.
- Consider the smallest possible component in graph $G$. It will have a vertex $v_i$ of degree $d$, and its neighbourhood $N_G (v_i)$ will consist of $d$ distinct vertices, all of degree $d$. So there are $d+1$ vertices of degree $d$. This is a complete graph of order $d+1$.
- Let the vertices in this component be $v_1, v_2,...,v_d,v_{d+1}$.
- Because these vertices are all connected to one another, there will exist an edge $e_1$ that connects $v_1$ and $v_2$, another edge $e_2$ that connects $v_2$ to $v_3$ etc. until we reach the edge which connects $v_d$ to $v_{d+1}$.
- So we have a walk from $v_1$ to $v_{d+1}$:
- $v_1,e_1,v_2,e_2,...v_d,e_d,v_{d+1}$
- This implies a path from $v_1$ to $v_{d+1}$ (noting that $v_1\neq v_{d+1}$) and there are $d$ edges in this path $=\delta(G)$.
- It follows that larger components of $G$ will still contain a path of length $\delta(G)$.

Is there anything I have overlooked? Are there any errors in my logic? It all makes perfect sense in my head but I'm worried that there may be some oversights in my steps above and I'm worried that the steps above won't make for a tight, neat proof. I'm all about the tight, neat proofs! Any feedback will be well-received. Thanks for your time, all.

Comment: The smallest component does not have to be a complete graph. Let $d = 3$, and such a complete graph would have $4$ vertices (like a square with both diagonals). However, the smallest component might have more vertices, say 6 (like a hexagon with some 3 diagonals). The path still exists, but it's not a complete graph.

Comment: Doesn't that violate $\delta(G)$?

Comment: There are degrees in that graph equal to 2.

Comment: There are 6 ends of the diagonals and 6 vertices: if you put the ends in different vertices, you will get a 3-regular graph.

Comment: Sorry, having trouble visualising it. Mind giving a degree sequence so I can draw it?

Comment: Ah, never mind! Got it. Thanks, I'll think about it.

Comment: Isn't the complete graph smaller than the one you presented?I mean the smallest $possible$ component. It could be bigger, but my thoughts were to show that there is a path in the smallest possible scenario and then it follows that the path still exists in larger components.

Comment: Why would that ensure that all bigger components have appropriate path? You cannot skip that question, that's the point of the proof. For example a star (a tree with once central vertex, and a lot of leaves) might be much bigger, but the longest simple path is of length 2.

Comment: I'm assuming we've switched from $d=3$ to $d=1$ now? The smallest possible graph in this case is $K_2$.

Comment: I'm just pointing that (bigger graph) => (has longer path) is not a valid inference. In other words, you have to do more that just prove it for a complete graph and say that's the worst case.

Comment: Damn, this chat doesn't offer enough characters to explain my reasoning. Never mind, though. I think I'll go see my professor. Face to face discussion may be better for this sort of thing. Thank you for your comments. I appreciate your time a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what the etiquette is on Math SE regarding answering old questions but I stumbled across this question and felt it would be good to drop an answer for future users that happen to ask the same question in the future.

Anyways, I'm going to do the particular case when $\delta(G) = 3$ and show that there exists a path of at least length 3. This can easily be generalized to $\delta(G) = n$ for any positive integer $n$.

So suppose $\delta(G) = 3$, then there exists a vertex $v_0$ such that $d(v_0) = 3$ (where $d(v)$ denotes the degree of a vertex $v$). Since $d(v_0)=3$, it has $3$ neighbors. Pick any neighbor and call it $v_1$. Notice that $d(v_1) \geq \delta(G) = 3$ so $v_1$ has at least three neighbors. Pick any neighbor of $v_1$, say $v_2$, such that $v_2 \neq v_0$ (which is possible since there are three neighbors to pick from). Similarly, $v_2$ has at least $3$ neighbors and it's possible to pick a neighbor of $v_2$, say $v_3$, such that $v_3 \notin \{v_0,v_1\}$. Thus you have the path,
$$ v_0 \to v_1 \to v_2 \to v_3$$
which is of length 3 as desired.

Comment: Appreciated! I'd forgotten about this problem!